# Plink Freezes After the sudo su - command

Tags: plink

I am trying to issue some commands remotely to a linux box from a windows machine using plink.exe and it's successfully executing all the commands except the **sudo su -**

In fact, it also does execute the sudo su - and I can see the output that *I am now superuser* but at this point it freezes so no any other commands can be executed.

This is what I'm using so far:

```
./plink.exe -ssh -v -pw myPassHere myUser@myHost "hostname;ls -la;sudo su - ; touch test.me"
```

I also tried to send that sudo su command to the background like this:

```
 ./plink.exe -ssh -v -pw myPassHere myUser@myHost "hostname;ls -la; sudo su - & touch test.me"
```

and this will execute the above commands including the **sudo su** but will add this:

```
logout root
stty: Not a typewriter
stty: Not a typewriter
stty: Not a typewriter
```

and close the connexion - still without executing the last **touch** command

Also tried adding both & and ; like this:

```
./plink.exe -ssh -v -pw myPassHere myUser@myHost "hostname;ls -la;sudo su -&;touch test.me"
```

And this gives me:

```
ksh: syntax error at line 1 : 'end of file' unexpected
```

I'm pretty sure that after issuing the sudo su - command the prompt expects a result and this is why it freezes but don't know how to pause for a while to allow the sudo su - command to execute or how to avoid the shell expecting an output.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need `sudo su -` in a non-interactive context (and this non-interactivity is what causes the "stty: Not a typewriter" error).

Just use `sudo touch test.me`.

Comment: I don't have the administrator password so in order to execute commands with admin rights I need to use **sudo su -**

Answer (score 0):

This approach is based on executions through command prompt.
Firstly, make sure Putty and Plink are added to your environment variables.
Then, try this code

```
try
                {
    // To connect using putty/plink
                String initialConnect = "cmd /c PLINK.exe -batch -i \"<path_to_keytab>\" <username>@<hostname>";
                //Eg.: String initialConnect = "cmd /c PLINK.exe -batch -i \"C:\\Users\\vsakaray\\Downloads\\private_key.ppk\" myuser@10.42.81.9";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(initialConnect);
                /* Get OuputStream */
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())), true);
                /* Storing list of commands to execute */
                String commands[] = { "sudo su user", "cd ~", "pwd" };
                /* Executing commands */
                for (String command : commands)
                {
                    writer.println(command.trim());
                }
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                int value = 0;
                InputStream std = p.getInputStream();
                /* Printing the console output */
                if (std.available() > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("STD:");
                    value = std.read();
                    System.out.print((char) value);
                    while (std.available() > 0)
                    {
                        value = std.read();
                        System.out.print((char) value);
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("DONE!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```